# Abrir arquivo em Modal Dialog

Tags: java, arquivo, bootstrap, modal

Estou recuperando um arquivo dado um caminho e gostaria de exibir a resposta em uma Modal.

Este é um trecho do HTML que faz a chamada ao servlet (MSD) passando o caminho do arquivo como parâmetro:

```
<a class="btn-doc-sm btn-default" type="button" href="MSD?p=d:/upload/documento.docx">
    Visualizar
</a>
```

Este é o trecho do meu servlet que recupera o arquivo e o exibe:

```
String caminhoArquivo = request.getParameter("p");
File arquivo = new File(caminhoArquivo);
String nome = arquivo.getName();
int tamanhoArquivo = (int) arquivo.length();
response.setContentType(acao);
response.setContentLength(tamanhoArquivo);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"" + nome + "\"");
output = response.getOutputStream();
Files.copy(arquivo.toPath(), output);
```

Com esse trecho, eu consigo recuperar o arquivo e exibi-lo, porém em uma nova aba.

Existe algum modo de que o arquivo recuperado seja exibido em uma modal?